# Laravel blade concatenate string if variable is not empty

Tags: laravel, if-statement, concatenation, laravel-blade

I'm trying to add an id attribute to a link if a given variable is not empty. To do so I'm using the inline-if sentence.

```
<li><a {{ $link['element_id'] }}  != "" ? {{"id=" . $link['element_id'] }} : '' href="{{ url($link['url']) }}">{{$link['name']}}</a></li>
```

Output: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you issue is that it is out of the php itself. Did you try using

```
<li><a {{ $link['element_id'] != "" ? 'id=' . $link['element_id'] : ''}} href="{{ url($link['url']) }}">{{$link['name']}}</a></li>
```

And also a good practice is to use one type of quotes in the php code preferably single ones.

Comment: I had to remove the double quotes from your id="' . $link['element_id']. '" and then it worked well

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<li>
    <a @if($link['element_id']!="") {{"id=" . $link['element_id'] }} @endif href="{{ url($link['url']) }}" >
        {{$link['name']}}
    </a>
</li>
```

But if you really want to do it via "inline-if" (this should work):

Your issue is that your are not putting the php between the brackets.

```
<li>
    <a {{ $link['element_id']!= "" ? "id=" . $link['element_id'] : ''}} href="{{url($link['url'])}}">
        {{$link['name']}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional inside the blade mustache syntax:

```
<li><a id="{{ $link['element_id'] != '' ? $link['element_id'] : '' }} href="{{ url($link['url']) }}">{{$link['name']}}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should works:

```
<li>
    <a id="{{ $link['element_id'] !== '' ? $link['element_id'] : null }}" href="{{ url($link['url']) }}">
        {{ $link['name'] }}
    </a>
</li>
```